# Easier way of inserting results of Django return in localstorage

Tags: django, local-storage

I have a page set up to load the results of a Django db query into a drop down list.  Upon selection of an item, a table is generated with the relavant data.

Given the view method

```
def index(request):
    parentorg_list = Parentorgs.objects.all()
    context = {'parentorg_list' : parentorg_list}
    return render(request, "app/index.html", context)
```

and

```
{% for org in parentorg_list %}
  localStorage.setItem("{{org.parentorg}}", "{{org.parentorgName}}");
{% endfor %}
```

is there a way to add the items to the localstorage without Django generating ~500 lines of repeated `localStorage.setItem()`?  Or would I be better off in converting the index return to a JSON list for parsing?

Comment: I think this will be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Answer (score 5):

Make `index` return a json, something like this:

```
import json
def index(request):
    parentorg_list = json.dumps([{'key': p.parentorg,'value':p.parentorgName } for p in Parentorgs.objects.all() ]) 
    context = {'parentorg_list' : parentorg_list}
    return render(request, "app/index.html", context)
```

And in the template loop for the array:

```
var objects = {{ parentorg_list|escapejs }};
for(var i=0;i < objects.length;i++){
    var obj = objects[i];
    localStorage.setItem(obj.key,obj.value);
}
```

(I didn't actually tested the code but it should work)